# Web2py SmartGrid display data per user

Tags: python, web2py

I want to create a controller with an SQLFORM.grid that shows only what the user submitted.

I have two tables: one for teachers(users) and another for students. The teachers submit the student's info. How can I use the grid to show the students submitted per user?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a [Common Filter](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Common-filters) to the table to limit what is shown. If you want to show only records created by a user then your filter might look like:

```
common_filter = lambda query: db.blog_post.created_by == auth.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use smart grid i.e SQLFORM.smartgrid() instead of normal grid and for teacher table add data filed students as list:string so that you can add multiple student names who submitted to a teacher id.